# Batch file input and output same filename from command

Tags: batch-file

I am using a program to encrypt `.dll` and `.exe` for use with a USB license stick, how can I simplify my `.bat` script to input all files in a directory and output all files with the original filename but not have to type each line in the `.bat` script?

Here is an example:

```
call %programforencypting% -o:"%dir%\subdirectory\file.dll" "%dir%\file.dll
call %programforencypting% -o:"%dir%\subdirectory\file2.dll" "%dir%\file2.dll
call %programforencypting% -o:"%dir%\subdirectory\file3.dll" "%dir%\file3.dll
call %programforencypting% -o:"%dir%\subdirectory\file.exe" "%dir%\file.exe
```

Basically instead of having hundreds of lines with each filename but the same command can't I just use something to essentially wildcard it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with calling programs with referenced variables, so have caution.

Perhaps this will work? Or atleast help.

```
rem delayed expansion enabled by habit with 'for' loops.

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /r . %%G in (!dir!\subdirectory\*) do (
    call !programforencypting! -o:"!dir!\subdirectory\%%~nxG" "!dir!\%%~nxG
)
```

Let me know if this works or not, or you want me to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.dll *.exe') do call %programforencypting% -o:"%dir%\subdirectory\%%a" "%dir%\%%a"
```

as a batch line - if you're brave enough to want to retype it every time from the prompt, reduce all `%%a` to `%a`.